# BASE64 string to Image in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have tried decoding `BASE64` String to `Uint8List`

```
Uint8List _bytes =
    base64.decode('data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQ .........');
Image.memory(_bytes);
```

But getting error as, (Error on character :)

> Invalid character (at character 5)
>   data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxITEhUSEhMVFRUV...

How could I get rid of this issue?

Comment: you have to `base64.decode` data only: starting from `/9j/4AAQ .........'`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're using URI that contains data after comma as it is defined by [RFC-2397](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Syntax). Dart's [Uri](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.1/dart-core/Uri-class.html) class is based on RFC-3986, so you can't use it. Split the string by comma and take the last part of it:

```dart
String uri = 'data:image/gif;base64,...';
Uint8List _bytes = base64.decode(uri.split(',').last);
```

Example code will useful for beginners ☺️

```
GestureDetector(
onTap:(){
showDialog(context: context, builder: (context){
var img64 = snapshot.getStudentDetailModel?.courseDetails?.pscPaymetSlip;
final decodestring = base64Decode('$img64'.split(',').last);
Uint8List encodeedimg = decodestring;
  return AlertDialog(
         contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
         content: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                  Container(
                   height:300,
                   decoration: BoxDecoration(
                   image: DecorationImage(
                   fit: BoxFit.cover,
                   image: MemoryImage(encodeedimg))),),],),);
                                      });
                                      },
                   child:Text('View',                                                 textAlign:TextAlign.end),),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
final UriData data = Uri.parse(plFile.path!).data!;
print(data.isBase64);
```