# Invalid character (at character 77) when decoding a base 64 image to show using Image . memory ()

Tags: flutter, dart, encoding, base64

so i was trying to show an image using a base64 string in flutter using the following code:

```
class GeneratedImages extends StatelessWidget {
      const GeneratedImages({
        Key? key,
       required this.imageBytes,
   }) : super(key: key);
     final String imageBytes;

    @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Image.memory(
   const Base64Decoder().convert(imageBytes),
  errorBuilder: (_, object, stackTrace) {
    return const Center(
      child: Icon(Icons.image_not_supported),
    );
  },
);
}
}
```

When i run the code, the following error is shown

```
 FormatException: Invalid character (at character 77)
```

> The Base 64 string which i have is :
> /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAUDBAQEAwUEBAQFBQUGBwwIBwcHBw8LCwkMEQ8SEhEP
> ERETFhwXExQaFRERGCEYGh0dHx8fExciJCIeJBweHx7/2wBDAQUFBQcGBw4ICA4eFBEUHh4eHh4e
> Hh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh7/wAARCAEAAQA
> FK5uYR9j05ISHI/eMTjPTGCPbtWJqHi3xJcyBhew27548oKMDPAG7k9cV1UsJWTu3YyqYml6n//Z

**[The Full base64 string has been uploaded on this link (free to view and edit)](https://textdoc.co/319QZh7rEgdGbt26)**

**Any Help Will Be Appreciated**

Comment: The full error message should indicate the invalid character: a space.  Whitespace is not accepted by Dart's base64 decoder.  If you can't correct the base64 string at the source, you will need to remove the whitespace first (e.g. `base64.decode(imageBytes.replaceAll(RegExp(r'\s'), ''))`).

Comment: @jamesdlin i have uploaded the whole string on https://textdoc.co/319QZh7rEgdGbt26 and there doesn't seem to be any whitespace in it.

Comment: The string there is split across multiple lines.  You will need to remove the newline characters.  I've updated my comment.

Comment: i removed newline characters but i haven't found any whitespace at 77 either

Comment: I can decode your string fine after using `.replaceAll(RegExp(r'\s', '')` on it.  If you still can't get it to work, post a minimal, complete code example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246707/discussion-between-austin-and-jamesdlin).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the answer suggested in the comments by [@Jamesdlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179715/jamesdlin) .

Removing all whitespaces present in the string will solve the problem .

Was able to remove whitespaces by using this :

```
 base64.decode(imageBytes.replaceAll(RegExp(r'\s+'), '')),
```

Comment: I'd recomment using `r'\s+'` as the regexp. Just because it handles `\r\n` more efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

If your Base64 string contains data after the comma as it is defined by [RFC-2397](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Syntax). Dart's [Uri](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.1/dart-core/Uri-class.html) class is based on RFC-3986, so you can't use it.

**Split the string by a comma and take the last part of it**:

```
String imgbase64 = 'data:image/gif;base64,...';
Uint8List _bytes = base64.decode(imgbase64.split(',').last);
```

REFERENCE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59015116/12382178